# upgraded to CodeIgniter 2.1, use of multiple databases in model now broken

Tags: model, codeigniter-2

I recently upgraded to CodeIgniter 2.1. The below model code (machforms_model.php) was properly working in my previous CI install. I have also confirmed that my database.php file is identical to the previous install, so db configuration should not be the source of my problem. The error message I see now is: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in models/machforms_model.php on line 24, where line 24 is my first query attempt.

```
machforms_model:php
class machforms_model extends CI_Model 
{

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->machformsdb = $this->load->database('machforms', TRUE);
        $this->machformsdb = $CI->machformsdb; 
    }


        function deauthorize_user($user_guid) {
        $sql = 'delete from ap_sessions where user_guid=?';
        $sql_result = $machformsdb->query($sql,array($user_guid));   // LINE 24     
    }
}
```

I am uncertain why I receive the overload error. If other external file/config information may be the culprit, please advise and I will post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$machformsdb` is not defined in your function `deauthorize_user`. You should call `$this->machformsdb`.

In addition: in your constructor, `$this` is already an instance of `CI_Model` so you don't need to get the CodeIgniter singleton instance. You could just write:

```
public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();  
  $this->machformsdb = $this->load->database('machforms', TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated. I'm curious as to why my (apparently sloppy) code worked in pre-2 CI? Thanks again!